# Android Shared Preference Values Not Persisting

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save user menu choices in my app via Android's [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) API. Despite successfully committing a '2' to my editor object via *editor.putInt("woodType", woodIntCode)* & *editor.commit()* when onStop() occurs, the value returned by settings.getInt("woodType", 0) during onCreate() is always 0.

Why isn't the preference file read returning a value of 2 for the woodType?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    //Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0); //MODE_PRIVATE = 0
    prefWoodColor = settings.getInt("woodType", 0);    //default color is 0 (dark wood) if no saved pref
}

//When app is stopped, update settings prefs so they persist into next launch
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    int woodKey = getGLSurfaceView().mRenderer.getWoodColor();

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("woodType", woodKey);

    // Commit the edits!
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Rather than call `getPreferences()` each time, call that once in `onCreate()` and hold onto the `SharedPreferences` in a field. Beyond that, rather than update the `SharedPreferences` in `onStop()`, update the `SharedPreferences` when the data changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Good suggestions in principle, but irrelevant to OP's problem, don't you think?

Comment: @TedHopp: I don't know which part you are disliking. I don't use `getPreferences()` much and do not know if the framework caches it. If it does not, I can see issues with having multiple `SharedPreferences` instances floating around representing the same backing store. With regards to `onStop()`, I worry about potential issues on configuration changes, where the new activity winds up with the old value because the old activity didn't get called with `onStop()` yet, and I do not know how the OP is testing this.

Comment: @CommonsWare Isn't it more efficient to update SharedPreferences only onStop? I don't see the benefit in updating everytime data changes since only the last configuration matters when determining the state to load into on next launch.

Comment: @Cody: "Isn't it more efficient to update SharedPreferences only onStop?" -- efficiency is less important than reliability, and right now you have a reliability problem. Get things working first, then ponder performance improvements. "I don't see the benefit in updating everytime data changes since only the last configuration matters when determining the state to load into on next launch" -- well, for example, if you crash, you will not have saved the state, because you delayed it after when the data logically changed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Just tested both of the requested edits, the problem is still unresolved.

Comment: @CommonsWare - The docs say that `getPreferences(int)` returns "The single `SharedPreferences` instance that can be used to retrieve and modify the preference values." As far as I know, `onStop` is _always_ called just before `onDestroy`. I'd be shocked if that didn't happen during the normal handling of configuration changes. (Cody: if you're worried about efficiency, then move saving the preferences to `onDestroy` instead of `onStop`, which can be called many times for an activity.)

Comment: @TedHopp Thanks, i've made this change. Will onDestroy be called in the event of an app crash?

Comment: Probably not. There's not much you can do to insure data integrity if the app crashes. If that's your main concern, then do as CommonsWare suggests and save whenever the data changes. As an aside, if you're targeting API level 9 or later, you should call `apply()` instead of `commit()`. It doesn't block the UI thread and is just as reliable (perhaps even more so, since it doesn't add to the risk of an ANR exception). For pre-9 targets, use `SharedPreferencesCompat` and `SharedPreferencesCompat.EditorCompat`.

Comment: While these changes may be best practice, the issue of non-persistency of the preference values still remains. What am I doing wrong?